# Uncaught reference error: .. is not defined .. but I can see the variable in the error string

Tags: php, javascript, variables

This line of code `var $sTest = <?php echo $a = $_GET['ID']?>` returns a "Uncaught reference error: .. is not defined."

For this question, if we assume I am passing an ID of "ABC."  When I use the Developer Tools in Chrome and inspect the Resources, I can see that the $_GET **has** worked because it shows me the variable value.  The error message in this case is "Uncaught reference error: ABC is not defined."

I can't work out how to assign the php variable to a script var.  Help appreciated.

Comment: Is `$sTest` meant to contain a string? If so, you need to put the PHP bit in quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you have to quote your php script's output:

```
var $sTest = <?php echo $a = $_GET['ID']?>
```

will became

```
var $sTest = something;
```

And in your Javascript enviroment the `something` is not defined. If you want to preserve as much type information as you can, you should use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on the php side like this:

```
var $sTest = <?php print json_encode($_GET['ID']);?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the final generated source code in the browser. You are missing quotes around the assignment:

```
var $sTest = "<?php echo $a = $_GET['ID']?>";
```

you should also apply `htmlspecialchars()` to the string to prevent XSS attacks and breaking out of the string:

```
var $sTest = "<?php echo $a = htmlspecialchars($_GET['ID']);?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing $_GET without assigning it to $a.

```
var $sTest = <?php echo $_GET['ID']?>
```

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: It will not solve his problem, it is just a way of getting more info.

Comment: Actually, I looked at it as a solution, not a way to get more info. But YMMV